# How to mock LayoutAnimation when testing React Native with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I am using Jest and [react-native-testing-library](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/) to test my components.

In one of my components I have the following code:

```js
const handleToggleFilters = () => {
  LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
  setPostFiltersActive(!postFiltersActive);
};
```

However, when testing my component, I get the following error

```sh
    TypeError: require(...).configureNextLayoutAnimation is not a function

      82 |
      83 |   const handleToggleFilters = () => {
    > 84 |     LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
         |                                  ^
      85 |     setPostFiltersActive(!postFiltersActive);
      86 |   };
      87 |
```

I added `jest.mock('react-native')` to my setup.js file but it then started complaining about other missing entities through the rest of my test suite ... do I have to mock the entire `react-native` library for this to work?

What is the best way around this?

Answer (score 7):

After looking at certain tests from `react-native` on github, it looked like they simple mocked the file themselves.

```js
// Libraries/Components/Keyboard/__tests__/Keyboard-test.js

jest.mock('../../../LayoutAnimation/LayoutAnimation');
```

So in my `setup.js` file I simply did

```js
jest.mock(
  '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LayoutAnimation/LayoutAnimation.js',
);
```

And my tests passed.